# Кнопка открывает скрытый текст, но затем не закрывает обратно

Tags: javascript, html, css

Написал код по видео и переделал его под себя. Изначально, вторая часть текста обернута спаном и ему задано свойство: display: none. При нажатии на кнопку display должен меняться на inline, чтобы появилась вторая часть текста.

А затем, при нажатии на кнопку второй раз этот span с текстом должен исчезать. Но срабатывает только первая часть плана: текст появляется. А дальше не фурычит.

В чем может быть дело?

код html:

```
<div class="text__container">
<p class="text-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum asperiores explicabo, et reprehenderit eum officiis! Nesciunt ea eaque deserunt nostrum omnis, asperiores eius quod inventore illo rerum eveniet, maxime cum?</p>
<p class="text-2" ><span id="more">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti debitis temporibus laborum. Vel, non exercitationem animi doloremque ratione ab ullam, nemo quia laboriosam asperiores, repellat corrupti cum dolor harum necessitatibus.</span></p>
</div>

<button class"text__button" id="btn" onclick='readMore()'>Читать далее</button>
```

код css:

```
#more {
  display: none;
}
```

код js:

```
function readMore(){
  let more = document.getElementById('more');
  let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
  
  if(more.style.display === 'none'){
    btn.innerHTML = 'Читать далее';
    more.style.display = 'inline';
  } else {
    btn.innerHTML = 'Скрыть';
    more.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Comment: вы перечитайте условия в коде.... у вас буквально написано, если свойство ужЕ **none**, то установить **none**........... если НЕ **none** то установить **inline**

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я поменял свойства местами. Работает, но при первом нажатии надпись на кнопке "Читать далее" меняется на "скрыть" и все. При уже втором клике на изменённую кнопку она открывает вторую часть текста, а надпись на кнопке меняется на "Читать далее". При нажатии на эту кнопку текст скрывается, но вместо "Читать далее" изменяется вновь на "Скрыть" хотя там должно быть написано другое. В общем, вот код, чтобы было понятно что я объясняю: https://codepen.io/maksimenkovvv/pen/KKeYjyw. Код в вопросе правил

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант...

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
    #more.off {
      display: none;
    }
    </style>
    <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', _ => {
        document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function () {
            document.getElementById('more').classList.toggle('off')
            this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML === 'Скрыть' ? 'Читать далее' : 'Скрыть'
        })
    })
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="text__container">
        <p class="text-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum asperiores explicabo, et reprehenderit eum officiis! Nesciunt ea eaque deserunt nostrum omnis, asperiores eius quod inventore illo rerum eveniet, maxime cum?</p>
        <p class="text-2" >
            <span id="more" class='off'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti debitis temporibus laborum. Vel, non exercitationem animi doloremque ratione ab ullam, nemo quia laboriosam asperiores, repellat corrupti cum dolor harum necessitatibus.</span>
            </p>
    </div>
    
    <button class"text__button" id="btn">Читать далее</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых у вас там в HTML синтаксическая ошибка: в последней строке пропал знак `=` в присвоении имени класса.
А во вторых, что куда важнее, вы бы попробовали ради отладки, прежде чем ставить условие `if`, сделать вывод переменной, которую проверяете `console.log(more.style.display)` и сразу бы всё поняли.

```js
function readMore(){
  let more = document.getElementById('more');
  let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
  if(more.style.display === 'none'){
     more.style.display = 'inline';
     btn.innerHTML = 'Скрыть';
    
  } else {
    more.style.display = 'none';
    btn.innerHTML = 'Читать далее';   
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="text__container">
<p class="text-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum asperiores explicabo, et reprehenderit eum officiis! Nesciunt ea eaque deserunt nostrum omnis, asperiores eius quod inventore illo rerum eveniet, maxime cum?</p>
<p class="text-2" ><span id="more" style="display: none">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti debitis temporibus laborum. Vel, non exercitationem animi doloremque ratione ab ullam, nemo quia laboriosam asperiores, repellat corrupti cum dolor harum necessitatibus.</span></p>
</div>

<button class="text__button" id="btn" onclick='readMore()'>Читать далее</button>
```

**P.S. UPD:** Надеюсь вы заметили куда переехал ваш CSS и поняли почему. Однако, если вы хотите пользоваться внешней таблицей стилей, то и проверять текущее состояние элемента потребуется несколько иначе: `window.getComputedStyle(more).getPropertyValue("display")`